# Configure automatically Angular value provider

Tags: angularjs

My Angular SPA app has a value provider. This provider is injected to all controllers.  At deployment time, I manually comment/uncomment which value to be used.  I wonder if there is a way to automatically toggle the values base on web.config like mechanism?  Thanks.

```js
'use strict';

// Demonstrate how to register services
// In this case it is a simple value service.
angular.module('myApp.services', [])

.value('version', '5.0')

//local IIS7
//.value('myWebApiEndpoint', 'http://localhost/CMT Data Service/api/')

//staging IIS
.value('myWebApiEndpoint', 'https://staging.myOrg.org/wcf_webapi/data%20service/api/')

//production IIS
//.value('myWebApiEndpoint', 'https://production.myOrg.org/wcf_webapi/data%20service/api/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the hard coded value, I add the following to the Angular value provider module in _layout.cshtml

```html
<script>
  angular.module("myApp.services")
    .value("version", '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appVersion"]')
    .value("webApi1Endpoint", '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webApi1Endpoint"]')
    .value("webApi2Endpoint", '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webApi2Endpoint"]')
</script>
```

section in _Layout.cshtml